# Python connect mysql show processlist INFO = Null

Tags: python, mysql, process, info

When I use pymysql and sqlalchemy.create_engine queries on my MySQL server.There are so many connections sleep.I want see the query language by process INFO so I can dispose or close the connect,but the **processlist** **Info** is Null.So How can I see detail query SQL of process.

My query process SQL

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist;
```

show
[image]

Comment: If a connection is not executing a query (it is in sleep status), then what exactly do you expect to see in the info column? Also, what you are seeing there is probably a result of sqlalchemy's connection pooling: it creates and maintains multiple connections in the background and reuses them as it sees fit. If the number of open, yet idle connections are causing a problem, then I would suggest you to take a look at the connection pooling settings of sqlalchemy. Closing connections will probably not achieve the expected results.

Comment: Oky.I understand.Thank you for your answer.So appreciate.